# How do I start a browser in Ubuntu on a PC?

Tags: command, prompt

Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot start my browser through the Ubuntu command line prompt.  My instructor plainly says to use the command "start example.html" (I'm on PC), but when I attempt it I keep getting "Command 'start' not found, did you mean":

command 'smart' from deb smartpm-core
  command 'stat' from deb coreutils
  command 'startx' from deb xinit
  command 'tart' from deb tart
  command 'rstart' from deb x11-session-utils
  command 'kstart' from deb kde-runtime

Try: sudo apt install

Comment: Just run `firefox` in your shell.

Comment: Thanks Erich! I'm installing firefox now.  What if I wanted to run it in Chrome?

Comment: Does [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-chrome-ubuntu/) help you? There is an open source alternative of chrome called `chromium`. You can start that one by calling: `chromium-browser`.

Comment: Thanks buddy.  I appreciate your time!

Comment: Now I'm getting this message:$ firefox
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

Comment: Is this a shell only session? Do you have a window manager?

Comment: You can try: `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Comment: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0.0

Comment: Are you running this on a headless machine? aka a server? If so run `startx`.

Comment: I am running this on a ASUS Vivobook with WIndows 10.  I am very new to this Erich so please bear with me and I thank you for your help.  I started App Academy yesterday and I followed the instructions for PowerShell, Visual Studio, Git, and Ubuntu but I cannot get a browser to open from the command line

Comment: Wait a minute, you are on Windows and you have some kind of linux emulator?

Comment: Yes per instructions in my class

Comment: And you only have shell access?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I have Chrome and Windows Edge installed

Comment: Does this help you? https://seanthegeek.net/234/graphical-linux-applications-bash-ubuntu-windows/ I guess you have to install an `X` server for windows to be used by linux first.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I'll check it out.  You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
firefox
```

In the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Entering `explorer.exe .` into the command line allowed me to then set Chrome as the default browser for my work